# Install Zathura on macOS 10.10.2

Tags: macos, pdf, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install Zathura on a Mac OS X 10.10.2. I have downloaded Zathura 0.3.2 and tried to run `make` but it requires girara. Girara requires gtk 3.2 but `brew install gtk+3` only installs 3.14.

Does anyone know a set of procedures to install Zathura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the adding the following to my `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
export $PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10
```

I could then `make` and `make install` without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question and answer is about 6 years old, here's a current method for Big Sur as of writing (expanding on my edit of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386671) on Ask Different).

I originally tried to compile it using the suggested method in the [documentation](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/installation/) which is [this MacPorts port](https://ports.macports.org/port/zathura/). Although it compiles, it gives the error `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display` when running. There are fixes for other ports of programs with the same error but instead, I found a [Homebrew tap](https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura) which installs it without issues.

To install:

```sh
brew tap zegervdv/zathura
brew install zathura
brew install zathura-pdf-mupdf
mkdir -p $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura
ln -s $(brew --prefix zathura-pdf-mupdf)/libpdf-mupdf.dylib $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura/libpdf-mupdf.dylib
```

There is work to integrate the program better into macOS but it's still in development - [see here](https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura#osx_native_integration).

Comment: Thanks! What are the differences between `mupdf` and `poppler`?

Comment: It looks like `mupdf` is faster than `poppler` at rendering PDFs, but not sure otherwise.